# Is there a way to make a bootable Linux live USB disk from a Linux docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that's based on the phusion/baseimage image. I'm new to Docker, but the way I understand it, this is basically a tiny Linux VM. It has lots of custom packages installed and a custom configuration. Is there a way to make this a bootable live USB disk, so I can boot directly into it?

Comment: While it ***may*** be technically feasible, it would require an enormous amount of effort to do.  It would be much simpler and logical to adapt an existing bootable USB disk to your container's configuration, although that could also represent quite a bit of work depending on your experience.

Comment: I would not call a docker container a tiny VM. It is more of an overlay over the basic host OS and in that sense, incomplete. If you extract things from the container, you would have to provide larger parts of the host and docker as well to make a bootable system.

Comment: Why not create a bootable linux USB that contains Docker, and then run the container on that?

Comment: I have been looking for something similar and someone pointed me to a Mac product "[Parallels Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac)".  With this you can boot from a second partition along side your existing MAC session.  I'm unsure of the technology but it looks like parallel virtualisation similar to (_say_) KVM or QEMU

Comment: @Jon ... you may like to review this small video: [How to Run an Existing Linux Partition in VirtualBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9TePODkYME) (_youtube_).  This looks like exactly what I need to parallel test some programs on multiple '_machines_'.  Good luck.